# Log4cplus not formatting entries in the syslog and extra file

Tags: logging, log4cplus

I want to make Log4cplus to format entries in the syslog and extra file so the severity will be first, like that:

```
[ERROR] 2016-12-19 15:00:53.182Z [16538] int main(int, char**)  | This
is a ERROR message
```

Such formatting, and any other changes, using my config file, are reflected only for the console output.

In the syslog, formatting is not changing and is in this format:

```
Dec 19 15:19:34 e97ed7deb530 myApp: ERROR [361] myApp.cpp  - This is a ERROR message
```

In the extra file, formatting is not changing and is in this format:

```
2016-12-19 15:19:34+0000 [140675141003072] ERROR main <> - This is a ERROR message
```

Here is my config file:

```
log4cplus.appender.syslog=log4cplus::SysLogAppender
log4cplus.appender.syslog.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.syslog.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%T] %b %x - %m%n

log4cplus.appender.extra=log4cplus::RollingFileAppender
log4cplus.appender.extra.File=generated/obsidian-extra.log
log4cplus.appender.extra.MaxFileSize=200KB
log4cplus.appender.extra.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4cplus.appender.extra.layout=log4cplus::TTCCLayout
log4cplus.appender.extra.layout.ContextPrinting=enabled
log4cplus.appender.extra.layout.DateFormat=%F %T%z

log4cplus.appender.console=log4cplus::ConsoleAppender
log4cplus.appender.console.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%q}Z [%T] %M %x - %m%n

log4cplus.logger.main=ERROR, console

log4cplus.logger.main=DEBUG, default, extra, syslog
log4cplus.logger.LogTest=TRACE, extra, console, syslog
```

Changes in config file to formatting, only can be seen in the console output.

How can I make all the logs consistent across all the media: console, syslog and extra file?

Comment: What version of log4cplus is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working as designed and your only misunderstanding the syslog output:

```
Dec 19 15:19:34 e97ed7deb530 myApp: ERROR [361] myApp.cpp  - This is a ERROR message
```

I believe that the whole of `Dec 19 15:19:34 e97ed7deb530 myApp:` is what syslog itself adds. The rest is according to the layout you have specified. `ERROR [361] myApp.cpp  - This is a ERROR message` matches `%-5p [%T] %b %x - %m%n`.

As for the rolling file, you have specified `TTCCLayout`, which is specific layout. You ask for specific time stamp and you get it. The rest is thread ID, log level, etc.